# How to get better performance out of Html 5 video via canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I have a video tag on my page used with the canvas element. I have been experiencing some jittery/stutter in the video. Chrome was (unexpectedly) the worst as far as play back is concerned but all of the major browsers I have tested all had difficulty playing smoothly.

Here is the code:

```js
//This deals with drawing the video (the init is inside of a component not shown here)
function OnInit(e, f) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("video"),
      b = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      c = b.getContext("2d");
    a.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
      b.width = a.videoWidth;
      b.height = a.videoHeight
    });
    a.addEventListener("play", function() {
      var a = this;
      (function d() {
        a.paused || a.ended || (c.drawImage(a, 0, 0), setTimeout(d, 1E3 / 30))
      })()
    }, 0)
  }, 10)
};

//This mostly to prep the video for mobile/tablets  
function mobile() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i) || window.matchMedia("(max-device-width: 960px)").matches ? (document.getElementById("canvas").style.display = "none", a.removeAttribute("autoplay"),
    a.removeAttribute("loop")) : a.removeAttribute("controls");
}
```

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  object-fit: fill;
  -o-object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url('../video.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 600px;">
  <canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></canvas>
  <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop="loop" poster="video.jpg" oncanplaythrough="mobile()">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <img src="video.jpg" height="600" style="width: 100%;" />
  </video>
</div>
```

I will also note that the video sizes are about 25 MB (mp4) and 5 MB (webm). I have tried requestAnimationFrame instead of set timeout BUT I did not really see a difference (although its possible it was not implemented as well as it should have been). If anyone has any suggestions, or if there is anything I can do better I am happy to listen. Before upgrading the hardware I am looking to improve performance in the code first. Thank you.

Comment: Why render the video inside the canvas and not just overlay the canvas with transparent background over the video?

Comment: If I do it that way, do you think it would  increase performance as opposed to the way I am doing it now ? This is the first solution that worked for me and is basically why I stuck with this method. The video I have currently cannot letterbox and I am not sure if it will using the overlay.

Comment: Don't use setTimeout, [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) is what you need. Please show us your attempt with that. `ctx.drawImage` is a pretty fast method, browsers should handle it without problem

Comment: What is called by the `setTimeout(d, 1E3 / 30)`?  
Aren't you performing the drawing also in the `d` function which is missing here?

Comment: @ Kaiido OK I will try requestAnimationFrame, but which "set interval" should I get rid of above (or should I get rid of both in favor of requestAnimationFrame) ?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out (for some reason) when ever I switched the source tags in the video element around, it worked pretty good. Thank you guys for your contributions and input. Also I put in requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout but putting the webm video before the mp4 video seemed to do the trick.